# EXCEL VBA Skip blank row

Tags: excel, vba, rows, cells

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Dim rng As Range
Dim cell As Variant

Set rng = Range("C8:C12")

For Each cell In rng
    Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:H7").Copy Destination:=Sheets("Quantity").Range("XFD4").End(xlToLeft).Offset(-3, 3)
    Sheets("Quantity").Range("XFD1").End(xlToLeft).Offset(0, 1).Value = cell.Offset(1, -1).End(xlUp).Value
    Sheets("Quantity").Range("XFD2").End(xlToLeft).Offset(0, 1).Value = cell.Value
    Sheets("Quantity").Range("XFD3").End(xlToLeft).Offset(0, 1).Value = cell.Offset(0, 1).Value  
Next
End Sub
```

What I want to accomplish here is to `skip blank cell/row`. Because it will copy empty data to the sheet. Is there any method e.g. Not isEmpty or isBlank for this `For loop`? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to check `IsEmpty(cell)` to see if a cell is empty.

For example (untested):

```
For Each cell In rng
    If Not IsEmpty(cell) Then
        Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:H7").Copy Destination:=Sheets("Quantity").Range("XFD4").End(xlToLeft).Offset(-3, 3)
        Sheets("Quantity").Range("XFD1").End(xlToLeft).Offset(0, 1).Value = cell.Offset(1, -1).End(xlUp).Value
        Sheets("Quantity").Range("XFD2").End(xlToLeft).Offset(0, 1).Value = cell.Value
        Sheets("Quantity").Range("XFD3").End(xlToLeft).Offset(0, 1).Value = cell.Offset(0, 1).Value 
    End If 
Next
```

Comment: IsEmpty returns true if the cell has nothing and ff the cell is the result of a formula? or if retursn #N/A?

Comment: @JonathanRaulTapiaLopez It should return true only if the cell has nothing in it. #N/A is an error condition which can be tested by `IsError`